# Update UI Framework CSS for new Web Components

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I'm using Grommet as a UI Framework for my React page.  For web components not covered by Grommet (e.g. a web chat control) what is the easiest way to style the additional web components not covered by the Grommet CSS.  Would I just add my own custom.scss?

```
    @import "includes/colors";
    @import "includes/settings";
    @import "includes/card-size";

    webchat {

        body .wc-app, .wc-app button, .wc-app input, .wc-app textarea {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    ...

}
```

In my app.js file I have the folllowing import call...

```
import webachatcss from '../app/custom.scss';
```

Then under render() I have the following code

```
<Chat  classname='webchatcss' directLine=.... />
```

UPDATE: I have installed the SASS-loader and updated my webpack.config.js which now looks like this (rules section is the latest change).

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  entry: ['./index.html','./app.js'],
  output: { 
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/, 
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
      },
      {
        rules: [{
          test: /\.scs$/, 
          use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
            }, { 
            loader: "sass-loader"
          }]
        }]
      },
      { 
        test: /\.png$/, 
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.jpg$/, 
        loader: "file-loader" 
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
      alias: {
        react: path.resolve('node_modules/react'),
      },
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

The location of my error has now changed with the error now appearing in the scss (which appears to be a step closer).  However I still get the error "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import css files to your code and use those styles or you can create styles with react.

```
import '/path/to/your/css/style.css';

// and on your component
<WebChat className="webchat" />

// or

const styles = {
    webchat: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#303030'
    }
};

<WebChat style={ styles.webchat } />
```

Comment: Sorry one edit to this is that web chat style uses a SCSS instead of an css.  What i went ahead and did was create an scss file.

Comment: Have you created your app with create-react-app or using webpack?

Comment: I am using webpack

Comment: you can use [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I installed the sass-loader but I'm getting the following error....Module parse failed: [Path]\custom.scss Unexpected token (2:8).  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: I'm not good with webpack config. Did you make the required changes to your config file as it explains on modules git?

Comment: The interesting thing is that after doing the sass install and looking at my webpack.config.js it only added the lines to test css not scss.

Comment: At the modules page it says you need to chain css-loader and style-loader on your config. try to make changes on your config file. Someone with more knowledge about webpack might help better

Comment: Ahh you are right, let me try to make some additional changes there.  Appreciate the guidance, not very well versed in style sheets or react so this is new space for me.  Thank you for helping me to understand.

Comment: I have tried chaining the commands in my webpack.config.js and while the error now appears to have changed the error appears to continue.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question with the changes you made and the errors you get please?

Comment: The error I get is the following when trying compile in webpack ERROR in ./app/custom.scss  Module parse failed in C:\...\csutom.scss.  Unexpected token (3:7)  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this type

Comment: @kuruption213 your test config seems to be wrong `test: /\.scs$/, ` should be `test: /\.scss$/, `

Comment: Thanks i did find that after posting.  I then got an error for a sass-loader and did a npm install of the sass-loader and a css-loader.  Also updated my webpack.config to include   resolve: {
      modules: ['node_modules'].  I'm now getting errors with CSS but at least its no longer with the webpack but now seems to be concentrated with the scss file. For those who have a similar issue please make sure you follow all the comments.  Thanks to @bennygenel for all the help!